Availability of Quarkus Quartz extenion as a stable feature
We would like to use the Quartz extension in our app. as it could make scheduled tasks much easier to handle and more generally make things a lot simpler.
However, the fact that it is currently a 'Preview' feature is a bit of a setback. I have read the FAQ (https://quarkus.io/faq/#what-are-the-extension-statuses). If I understand rightly, as a Preview feature, there is no guarantee that it will be present in future versions.
Are there plans to move Quartz to "Stable" in the near future?
Thanks
P.S. I'm posting here because I asked here
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/44228
first but got no reply.

Quartz development has picked up recently and soon they will release 2.5.0 final which is Jakarta compliant.  Once that happens Quarkus can rip out all the code that "hacks" it to remove JAVAX for Jakarta as 2.5.0 will be fully Jakarta.
I think once that happens the component can be marked "stable" but I will tell you i use i in production and its quite stable as is!
Edit: Quartz 2.5.0 is officially released and Quarkus is updating to use it.

hi, thanks for your reply - sounds reassuring enough to consider the Quartz extension as a good candidate for handling our scheduled tasks.
